# Pass parameters from driver to executors in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am using spark 2.0.0.
Is there a way to pass parameters from spark driver to executors? I tried the following.

```
class SparkDriver {
     public static void main(String argv[]){
           SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("yarn");
           SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate(); 
           Dataset<Row> input = sparkSession.read().load("inputfilepath");
           Dataset<Row> modifiedinput = input.mapPartitions(new customMapPartition(5),Encoders.bean(Row.class));
     }

  class customMapPartition implements MapPartitionsFunction{
          private static final long serialVersionUID = -6513655566985939627L;
          private static Integer variableThatHastobePassed = null;

        public customMapPartition(Integer passedInteger){
             customMapPartition.variableThatHastobePassed= passedInteger;
         }
         @Override
          public Iterator<Row> call(Iterator<Row> input) throws Exception {
              System.out.println("number that is passed " + variableThatHastobePassed);
          }
   }
```

As mentioned above I wrote a custom mappartitionfunction to pass the parameters. and am accessing the static variable in call method of partitionfunction. This worked when i ran in my local with "setmaster("local"). But did not work when ran on a cluster with .setmaster("yarn"). (printed null in the system.out.println statements)

Is there a way to pass parameters from driver to executors.

Answer (score 0):

my bad i was using 
private static Integer variableThatHastobePassed = null;

the variable should not be declared as static.